# How to convert ga.js method to analytics.js code

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

Upgrading my site from ga.js legacy to analytics.js. I have a piece of code from classic ga.js that I need to upgrade to universal analytics.

How do I upgrade this code `onsubmit="ga(['_linkByPost', this]); return true;"` to universal analytics code? I use this code on a form for cross domain linking. Now I just have to figure out how to convert this to universal analytics.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you need to use *linker*.

```
ga('linker:autoLink', ['example-2.com'] );
```

See if this is what you're looking for:

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034342?hl=en

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/linker?hl=en